# How to write a file into a specific folder using Here package?

Tags: r, relative-path, filereference

I am trying to use *Here* to easy file referencing and it is working okay if I write pdf or csv files without any sys date. For example; `pdf(here("output/first.pdf))` works but not if I add any of the formatting text. Appreciate if you can help me how to make below code work with *Here*. Thanks!

```
pdf(file=paste0(projPath,format(Sys.Date(),"%Y%b%d"),".pdf"),
    height = 6, width = 16)
write.csv(df,file=paste(projPath,"/output/first_",format(Sys.Date(),"%Y%b%d"),".csv",sep=""), quote=F, row.names = F, na=".")
```

Comment: Are you saying `pdf(here(paste0(format(Sys.Date(),"%Y%b%d"),".pdf")))` didn't work? Or what exactly did you try? You just need to pass a string to `here()`. You can build that string with `paste0()` or `format()` or whatever you like.

Comment: Thank you @MrFlick. It worked. I wasn't using _paste0_ with _here_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend that you use the `glue` library, it makes injecting additions into strings a breeze.
See this example

```
library(here)
library(glue)

(mydate <- format(Sys.Date(),"%Y%b%d"))
here(glue("something_{mydate}.pdf"))
```